# measuring a bad motor and large current spikes in a brush motor

Tags: motor, current-measurement, testing

I am new to this forum, I am an EIT and I have been tasked to implement a fixture to measure high current spikes on brush motors when loaded and unloaded.

I am at a loss here as I have never assembled such a project, as I said I am an EIT. I have an idea that will measure the spikes in the 5v motor and result of the data collected will display a LED: red for faulty motor (high I); green fo non-faulty (good I).

I have software support, just need to figure out how I can create the schematic model.

Please if someone can point me in a direction that would be awesome. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is your maximum expected current and voltage?

Comment: The maximum voltage is 8v and I am looking at a current range between .600-.800mA

Comment: Please edit the expected voltage/current information into your question post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that the below circuit will do the trick.  You have a current sensor (I like the [INA139](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ina169.pdf)) which senses the motor current and outputs a current directly proportional to the motor current, peaks and all.

The diode doesn't allow the output voltage to be reversed, so the capacitor holds a charge that is proportional to the peak.  R1 acts as a slow 'bleed' resistor.

The comparator circuit does the comparison for you, with a little hysteresis.

You may have to adjust some resistance and capacitance values, but this should get you close.

Also, if you are interested, I have a breadboard current sensor laid out already and [somewhat documented](http://www.forembed.com/current-sensor-board-testing/).  It is open-source, so all of the information is there.

[image: schematic]

Comment: I went for lowest poss. component count in my circuits, assuming the OP wanted to continue using the software they stated was already developed. ahere, you "went the extra mile" and put everything together on one PCB for them. Nicely done, +1 ;)

Comment: No problem, good luck!  Since you were interfacing with software, I assumed that a digital out would be best.  At least it is here for posterity :)

Comment: WOW! Your awesome I was just asking for a direction, but you my friend stole the show! Thank you very much! I will put this together on my breadboard and play with it.

Comment: No problem.  You happened to catch me already having similar thoughts, so I was happy to share.  I thought that I was responding to you in my previous comment, but I see that I was answering Robherc.  His solution would work just as well if you have a differential input A/D card.  My solution just takes that to a digital.  After looking at it again, you may want to make one of the voltage divider resistors a potentiometer so you can easily adjust it.

Answer (score 0):

Here are 2 circuits that could work for your need.

The first circuit outputs a voltage that can be measured with a meter/adc to determine the current being used by the motor, and the second one can light an LED 'automatically' if the motor draws too much current.

[image: first circuit]

[image: second circuit]

R1 in both circuits is a "current sense" or "shunt" resistor. Use as small a resistance as possible, to have minimum effect on the motor's current draw, so long as it is large enough to provide a usable/measurable output voltage to your measuring equipment.

R2 in the 2nd circuit is a current-limiting resistor to keep the LED from being damaged if the motor leads are shorted, and should be sized based on your full input voltage being placed across the LED.

---

UPDATE based on OP information posted in comments.

8V, 0.6-0.8A anticipated load likely won't be enough to use the second circuit without adding other power components, but the first circuit should still work well for that. An R1 value of 0.125ohm would give ~100mV (0.1V) at the test leads, while still leaving a 7.9V supply to the motor, so should (in most circumstances) be adequate for reliable overcurrent detection without significantly affecting the reading/accuracy by "loading down" the circuit & dropping the available power to the motor under test.

Comment: This looks similar to what I am looking for. Since you know that I am new to this forum, how can I rate your profiles?

Comment: @TheEIT To vote an answer as "good," click the "up arrow" to the left of it; to vote one as "bad," click the "down arrow," (you can vote on every answer) and to select one answer as "answered my question"/"fixed my problem," click on the "circle & checkmark" next to that one answer (can only select one for that). - For more info, you can check out the [help] when you have some spare time. ;)